# Easy way of re-indexing my table

Tags: postgresql

Good Day,

I'm currently using posgresql as my backend and I have to make huge changes on my  table fields. 
I will be using two tables.

```
Table 1         Table 2

Old Index       New Index
Product Id      Old  Index
Address         Product Id
Contact no      Address
                Contact no
                Email
```

I have to migrate all details from Table 1 from Table 2.  I’m using a different index for Table 2. 
For my other tables to recognize my old index I used this query

```
Update Table 2 Set  OldIndex =Table2.index
From(select  Oldindex  from Table 1)as  new,Table 1
Where  Table1.Productid =Table2.Productid
```

I have other tables related to Table 1 so my goal is to replace the old index with new index and hope that other tables can see the changes too. 
But I’m not sure I’m doing this right. my query is slow, I hope someone can test my query and point me on the right direction if I'm doing it all wrong, thank you  in advance.

Comment: It isn't really possible to test your query if you post it rewritten with improper names and SQL syntax errors... Post your actual schema definitions and query; not some obfuscated variation thereof.

Answer (score 1):

Would you mind to try MERGE

```
MERGE INTO Table2 AS b
USING Table1 AS p
ON p.product_id = b.product_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN b.OldIndex = b.NewIndex
```

I do not know how it works for postgresql, but you can find some samples here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/MergeTestExamples

Comment: Merge isn't part of Postgres (yet).

Comment: Thanks Denis - I work with Oracle. Is there any equivalent for MERGE in Postgrees?

Comment: It's on the roadmap. But not present yet. (See the various postgres upsert-related threads for alternatives.)

Comment: Alas, `MERGE` and upsert isn't available in PostgreSQL. It's a real FAQ and causes a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this in PostgreSQL is to use a writable CTE (available in 9.2 and later).

In this way you would do something like:

```
WITH up (UPDATE table2
            SET ....
           FROM table1 t1
          WHERE t1.product_id = table2.product_id
         RETURNING product_id)
 INSERT INTO table2 (...)
 SELECT ... 
   FROM table1 
  WHERE product_id NOT IN (select product_id from up);
```

You can find some examples [here](https://github.com/JackC/writable-cte-examples).